# What flag should be used if someone write duplicate of your answer?

Tags: discussion, flags, duplicate-answers

I wrote an answer and I found that somebody else wrote the same answer (*consciously or unconsciously*) **for the same question** with very little modification.

I tried to raise a flag and options are -

- spam
- not an answer
- very low quality
- in need of moderator intervention

Which flag should I use. Because

- It's not a spam
- It's an answer too
- quality is good

So last resort is to raise ***in need of moderator intervention***.

---

Is informing moderator for a duplicate answer right choice here?

Can't we have a duplicate answer flag?

Comment: That just looks like a bad answer, an empty string for the path can't be correct.  Just solve it yourself and downvote bad answers, no moderator needs to be involved with that.  The poster usually takes the hint and deletes his post.

Comment: if you can make solid points that other answer is [meta-tag:plagiarism] (and not, say, just a usual [meta-tag:fastest-gun] race), raise custom flag for moderator